# Changing Xamarin Themes,styles per client approach

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

what approach would you use if you have a mobile app build using xamarin and this app is like a vanilla app.

Each client should be able to apply their own style to labels etc.. theme

Basically all the views/pages are the same for all the clients but the style per page will change for each individual client.

If this wasn't a mobile app I would have plugins within a folder and depending on the client i would drop the relative plugin in the pluginFolder eg:pluginClientA etc.. and this would be discovered at runtime usin mef.

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Set you styles up as dynamicresources as seen here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/dynamic/

I only have 2 themes so I have them specified in xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="Primary">#337ab7</Color>
        <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#C0C0C0</Color>
        <Color x:Key="TextColor">White</Color>

        <!-- Buttons -->
        <Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48" />
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" ></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="80" Android="80" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="150" Android="150" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="btnPrimary" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource buttonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource TextColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Primary}" />
        </Style>

        <!--Light Theme-->
        <Color x:Key="Primary-Light">#2196F3</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor-Light">#FAFAFA</Color>
        <Color x:Key="TextColor-Light">White</Color>

        <!--Dark Theme-->
        <Color x:Key="Primary-Dark">#1976D2</Color>
        <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor-Dark">#C0C0C0</Color>
        <Color x:Key="TextColor-Dark">Black</Color>

    </ResourceDictionary>
```

So in the theme change event you can change the assigned colours

```
Resources ["Primary"] = Resources ["Primary-Dark"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I had already seen it ,but not sure how would it work.Suppose I have 2 clients ClientA and ClientB which both share the same portable class library with all the views.How would it work.Any samples?

Comment: added an example

Comment: Thank you very much for adding an example I will try to put one together later on to see whether it works for me .but can you have the resource dictionary coming from 2 differently assemblies.EG ClientA.Styles and ClientB.Styles and then somehow the portable can implement one or the other.Hopes it makes sense what I am trying to achieve. "Each client to be able to run the same app with different styles

Comment: I haven't tried before, but I would assume you could create the color in the code behind and assign it to the Resource dictionary, replacing the standard theme.